# Add 'Purchased' items column back into Woocommerce order admin view?

Tags: function, woocommerce, hook

In the latest version of Woocommerce (3.0.4), the 'Purchased' order items column has disappeared! This used to appear in the orders admin area.

Can anyone advise on how to hook this column back into the main orders view?

Comment: -UPDATE-
Just found that Yith have created a plugin exactly for this purpose!

https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-purchased-column-for-woocommerce/

Answer (score 2):

-UPDATE-
Just found that Yith have created a plugin exactly for this purpose!

https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-purchased-column-for-woocommerce/

Comment: For those, who doesn't like to use much plugins of their website, the snippet for the functions.php can be found https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/columns.html#purchased_products_column